# LMAX's disruptor. How to define multi EventHandlerGroup?

Tags: java, disruptor-pattern, lmax

I want to handle different event with multi-EventHandleGroup?I can't find example with that.thanks...
it's the code:

```
  executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPoolSize);
  disruptor = new Disruptor<>(new DefaultEventFactory(), 
  ringBufferSize, executorService
     , ProducerType.SINGLE, new BlockingWaitStrategy());
  EventHandlerGroup<OrderEvent> orderEventEventHandlerGroup = 
  disruptor.handleEventsWith(
     new OrderEventHandle(rabbitTemplate));
  orderEventEventHandlerGroup.then(new 
  MoveEventFromProcessing(redisService))
     .then(new EventClearHandle());
```

I want to add another event and I want to handle it with another EventHandleGroup like:

```
cancelEventDisruptor.handleEventsWith(new 
CancelOrderHandle()).then(new MoveEventFromProcessing(redisService))
     .then(new EventClearHandle());
```

Comment: Please add more details to your question.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please edit the question to show what you've tried. Like this we will be able to better understand your problem/question and thus we will be able to better help you. It is best to provide a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [Ask] and take the [Tour].

Comment: I have update it.thanks

Answer (score 0):

All `eventHandlers` see all messages. To achieve what you are looking for your `OrderEventHandle` and `CancelOrderHandle` need to be able to establish the type of event seen and ignore the ones which do not apply to them.

In the example code you are also setting up two complete handling chains. You would be better advised to have a single `MoveEventFromProcessing` gated (see [SequenceBarrier](https://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/docs/com/lmax/disruptor/SequenceBarrier.html)) on both the `OrderEventHandle` and `CancelOrderHandle` and then gate the `EventClearHandle` on that. So the topology would look like

`Producer -> RB -> OrderEventHandle  -> MoveEventFromProcessing -> EventClearHandle
              \-> CancelEventHandle /`